# Ruby random numbers in row

Tags: ruby, random, numbers

I have this ruby code:

```
puts (0..5).map{rand(0..10)}
```

the output =>

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

How will I make this in rows without comma? Like => `12345`

Thanks!

Comment: `puts (0..5).map{rand(0..10)}.join('')`

Comment: Great! But how can I pick the first three numbers in this? FOr example => 123

Comment: `puts (0..5).map{rand(0..10)}.first(3).join('')`

Comment: If you want only three, why generate 6 ? Use `(1..3).map{rand(0..10)}.join('')`

Comment: great. i understand but if I generate my first 6 numbers => 18913 and from that I just want to get the first 3 numbers => 189.

Comment: Note if you use `rand(0..10)` then some of your numbers will be `10` - so you need to be clear first 3 *numbers* or first 3 *digits*? Or is that a bug/misunderstanding and really you want `rand(0..9)`?

Comment: the first 3 numbers of the random numbers that I generate.

Comment: arr =(0..4).map{rand(0..9)}.join ('')
puts arr

puts arr.take(3) => here's my code, but it was error, should I use take or first (3)?

Comment: updated my answer to help you out with your second question

Comment: To avoid creating near-duplicate questions, it may help if you explain a little more about what you are trying to do. Your question seems to have two related parts. 1) Using only part of an array of random numbers. 2) Displaying that part in a particular fashion. Most importantly, what `puts` writes to your screen is only relevant if your goal is to see something specific on the screen - it is not the same as the data.

Comment: Great! 1. I want to generate the random number that is for example => 12345 2. From that random numbers, I want to get the first numbers that is =>123. So my output should be => 12345, 123. I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Armit is right:

If you generate an array with your function:

```
arr = (0..5).map{rand(0..10)}
# => [4, 5, 9, 9, 5, 6]
```

then you simply have to join these elements without a comma

```
arr.join('')
# => '459956'
```

**Update**

When you only want to work with the first three elements, you can simply select them with

```
first_three = arr[0..2] # note the indexing starts at 0
first_three = arr.take(3) # works fine aswell
# => [4, 5, 9]
```

When you have the desired elements, you can `join` them into a string or do whatever you desire

Comment: got it! thanks. what if from the 6 ramdom numbers that I generate, I want to take the first 3 numbers so my output will be => 123456, 123.

Comment: Well, its the same as the `arr` with 6 elements that got converted to a string with `join`... Simply do the same with your new array `first_three`